# TypeError: headers[key].trim is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to execute an API on AWS, that requires a CORS headers, i make the request with all the information but i receive the next error:

"TypeError: headers[key].trim is not a function"

If i not send de CORS, i receive the error:

from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

**My code:**

```
async function Request(){
    let arra = "test"
    const data2 = {
        "parm1" : "one", "parm2" : "two"
    };
    const headers = {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true
    };
    try{
        const resp = await API.post("Lambda", "/admin/digital/app/uploadtodynamo", {
            body: data2, headers: headers
        });
        console.log("error 1")
        console.log(resp)
    }
    catch(error)
    {
        console.log("error 2")
        console.log(error)
    }
}
```

React version: "^16.12.0"

Amplify: "^2.2.5"

Comment: Sorry, i miss write "headers:headers". API is form AWS Amplify, a framework for work with AWS. import { API } from "aws-amplify"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Header Values have to be strings. At some point during sending your request, you (or some library) are trimming the header values from trailing and leading whitespaces. But as the value of the Access-Control-Allow-Credentials header is a boolean and not a string this doesn't work.

Change

```
"Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true
```

to

```
"Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true"
```

Comment: I receive this: from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: Your server does not add the required cors headers when answering.

Comment: BTW there is no need to send the CORS headers from the client to the server. But the server must include the CORS headers in its response to the client.

Comment: You're correct derpirscher, i added the CORS in the answer of the lambda, and immediately works. (PD: I dont know how to mark as solution)

Comment: @MateoBuitrago Just click the checkmark next to the answer

Answer (score 2):

Chiming in, I got this error when using `Metadata`. One of my fields was a number.

```js
const uploaded = await sendUploadCommand(new PutObjectCommand({
    ACL: "authenticated-read",
    Bucket: myBucket,
    Body: file,
    Key: `/${folder}/${filename}.${r.ext}`,
    ContentType: r.mime,
    Metadata: {
        userId: user.id, // A string, this is fine
        flags: user.flags // ← A number, this is the error! Add '.toString()'
    }
}));
```

The documentation states that `Metadata` should be KV of strings:
`PutObjectRequest.Metadata?: {[p: string]: string}`

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error due to providing incorrect `Tagging`-value to my `PutObjectCommand`.

It should be a key-value formatted string, i.e. `"key=value;key=value"`. However, I accidentally supplied a boolean, `false`:

```
async function uploadFile(fileContent, fileKey, contentType, tagging) {
  try {
    await s3.send(
      new PutObjectCommand({
        Bucket: UploadBucketName,
        Key: fileKey,
        Body: fileContent,
        Tagging: tagging, // <-- ERROR
      }),
    );

    const getCommand = new GetObjectCommand({
      Bucket: UploadBucketName,
      ContentType: contentType,
      ACL: 'public-read',
      Key: fileKey,
    });

    return getSignedUrl(s3, getCommand, { expiresIn: 3600 });
  } catch (e) {
    throw new Error(`Could not upload file to S3 ${e}`);
  }
}
```

Protip: Use TypeScript.